# conflicting Jquery & javascript

Tags: jquery

I have 2 jquery script and 1 javascript which are conflicting with each other.

Below is code. Please let me know how to resolve this

1.) jquery for calender

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getCityDate(cityName,StarType)
{
    if(cityName && StarType)
    {
        // Call the php page to get the HTML
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxSearchHotelDateSelect.php?cityName='+cityName+'&StarType='+StarType,
            success: function(responseHTML) {
                // Set the HTML somewhere on the page - note: if you are returning a full page of HTML you shouldn't include all the <html><body> tags etc...
                $("#homeMainTextDiv").html(responseHTML);
                // Now that your HTML is available in the DOM you can initiate the datepicker()
                $("#StartDate").datepicker({
                    numberOfMonths: 3,
                    minDate: "0", 
                    maxDate: "+1Y",
                    dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy",
                    /*

                    altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                    maxDate: "+3M +10D",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    showWeek: true,
                    firstDay: 1,

                    */
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "images/calander_hotel_booking_final.png",
                    showAnim: "slideDown",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true
                });
            }
        });

    }//if(cityName && StarType)
}
</script>
```

2.) jquery for auto complete

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ajax-autocomplete/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery/ajax-autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ajax-autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $("#searchText").autocomplete("ajaxSearchAutoComplete.php", {
        width: 750,
        matchContains: true,
        mustMatch: true,
        minChars: 3,
        //multiple: true,
        //highlight: true,
        //multipleSeparator: ",",
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>
```

3.) Javascript for pop window with blackout screen

```
<body onload="Popup.showModal('modal',null,null,{'screenColor':'#333333','screenOpacity':.5});return false;" >

<script src="js/popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<center>
    <div id="modal" style="border:0px solid #0066FF ; padding:5px; font-size:150%; text-align:center; display:none; width:300px; height:250px;">
        <a href="index.php" target="_self"></a><input type="image" src="images/close.png" width="30" height="30" alt="X" onClick="Popup.hide('modal')" style="cursor:pointer; float:right;">                            
        <div style="background:url(images/homeDateSelectionBg.png) no-repeat left top; width:292px; height:192px; margin-top:25px;">

        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

If I remove auto comlete jquery and pop up javascript, calender fine work fine else not .

How to fix that? My calender is coming via ajax and in pop window.

Comment: you are loading jQuery twice...

Comment: And two different versions as well!

Comment: @AS just try using the first one and remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ajax-autocomplete/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: removed but still calender not working

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a js error which is not letting you to run your other js code.
Replace

```
$().ready(function() {
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: The above is not working. Problem is that calender jquery stop working when we enable autocomplete jquery and pop js.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'datepicker'

Comment: make sure you have included jQuery library only once in the page.

Comment: ya it is jquery version problem. I was calling 2 jquery. Thanks